# Invalid event target - when using fromEvent with Angular Material Button

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material

I am trying to setup a click event to a Button dynamically using `fromEvent` and `defer` modules of `rxjs`.
It works fine when using normal html button, but doesn't work with Angular Material button.

Here is the code works fine with Normal Button:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { defer, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
    <button #testBtn>Click me</button>
  `
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('testBtn', { static: true }) testBtn: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
  event$ = defer(() => fromEvent(this.testBtn.nativeElement, 'click')).pipe(
    map(() => new Date().toString()),
    tap(console.log)
  )
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.event$.subscribe();
  }
}
```

And here is the code which doesn't work with Angular Material Button

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { defer, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
    <button mat-raised-button #testBtn>Click me</button>
  `
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('testBtn', { static: true }) testBtn: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
  event$ = defer(() => fromEvent(this.testBtn.nativeElement, 'click')).pipe(
    map(() => new Date().toString()),
    tap(console.log)
  )
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.event$.subscribe();
  }
}
```

I couldn't guess why this problem is happening.

Can you help me understand it ?

Comment: Can you console.log this.testBtn.nativeElement with native button and mat-button and compare. Does it the same?

Comment: That's `undefined` in the case of Material Button and `HTML Button` in the case of Native Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** add it `{ read: ElementRef }` your ViewChild;

Use it for your matButton.
@ViewChild("myButton", { read: ElementRef }) myButtonRef: ElementRef;
You need to use your button as nativeElement ElementRef;

Comment: That's great it worked!!! Thanks. Do you know the reason behind it why it wasn't working without `{ read: ElementRef }` ?

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/  Read this article about ViewChild. This article describes the argument {read: }.